# Align search input in the middle of li - CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a big problem and I can't solve it.

I have a top menu with a image on the left and a search box on the right.
I want this search box to stay in the middle, but line-height is not working there... I don't know what to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/5mdz2zp9/

```
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 //background-color:#eee;
 background-color:#F5F6FA;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size:12px;
}

*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}


#menu {
 background-color: rgba(35,35,35,.9);
 //border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
 position:fixed;
 width:100%;
 top:0;
 margin:0;
 //padding: 0;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 height:50px;
 z-index:100;
}
#menu a:link, #menu a:visited, #menu a:hover{
 color: #fff;
}
#menu ul{
 display:table;
 width:100%;
 list-style-type: none;
}
#menu li{
 text-align:left;
 display: table-cell;
 width:50%;
 border:1px solid yellow;
}
.right{
 text-align:right !important;
 padding-right:10px;
}
#menu img{
 margin-left:10px;
 max-height:40px;
}
.search{
 padding-left:10px;
 padding-right:10px;
 padding-top:4px;
 padding-bottom:4px;
 border:1px solid #fff;
 border-radius:7px;
 color:#555;
 font-weight:bold;
}
```

html

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href=""><img src="https://infooab.examtime.com/wp-content/themes/learn/img/flashcard_shortcode_icon.png"></a></li>
<li class=right><form class="searchform"><input type="text" name="search" class="search" placeholder="search"></form></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

How can I align input in the middle vertically without let image size on the left interfearing?
Thank you friends!

Comment: use vertical-align:middle in #menu li..simple..

Comment: @Leothelion post an answer?

Comment: @AlexChar, thanx a ton man..:) its kinda hard to find people like you..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So posting as answer..

Please add this in your css and your box will be in middle..please be in mind when you are using display;table-cell then use vertical-align..hope it will help..:)

```css
#menu li{vertical-align:middle;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
#menu ul {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

to this:

```
#menu ul {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and this:

```
#menu li {
    text-align:left;
    display: table-cell;
    width:50%;
    border:1px solid yellow;
}
```

to this:

```
#menu li {
    text-align:left;
    display: table-cell;
    width:50%;
    border:1px solid yellow;

    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c9n3s4ym/)

Answer (score 0):

**css**

```
#menu li {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
}
```

**working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5mdz2zp9/2/)**